# PHP get variable in function from foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, foreach

I am working on some plugin in wordpress and I have following array and foreach loop with function in it.

Problem is that somehow I always getting $locale_key variable same as $code when $locale_key variable is inside function.

Please help.

```
$languages = array(
    array('af', 'af', 'Afrikaans'),
    array('ar', 'ar', 'العربية', 'rtl'),
    array('az', 'az', 'Azərbaycan'),
    array('be', 'bel', 'Беларуская мова'),
    array('bg', 'bg_BG', 'български'),
    array('bs', 'bs_BA', 'Bosanski'),
    array('ca', 'ca', 'Català'),
    array('cs', 'cs_CZ', 'Čeština'));

$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];

foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
    $locale_key = $languages[$key][1];
    $code = $languages[$key][0];
    echo $locale_key; // Here i get for example "bs_BA"
    add_shortcode( $code, function($atts, $content = null, $locale_key) {
        global $lang;
        echo $locale_key; // And then here i get "bs"
        if ($lang == $locale_key) {
            return $content;
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is $languages[$key][1] from array, but i always get $languages[$key][0]

Comment: Can you please tell us what do u need as a output?

Comment: for example when in foreach loop $code is 'bs' i want to $locale_key be 'bs_BA', and that work if I echo variable outside function, but when i echo variable inside function i get same as $code variable. 

function($atts, $content = null, $locale_key) {
        global $lang;
echo $locale_key;
});

I will get bs, not bs_BA what I need.

Comment: Is `add_shortcode()` your created function?

Comment: add_shortcode() is wordpress function

Comment: So the `$lang` is your session is the code. Then that code will search in the array of $languages. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, and when $lang is same as $locale_key then it return content for that language.

Comment: Can you print_r($languages)?

Comment: I can outside function, but inside i can't.

Comment: Yeah. Print that please.

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => af
            [1] => af
            [2] => Afrikaans
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ar
            [1] => ar
            [2] => العربية
            [3] => rtl
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => az
            [1] => az
            [2] => Azərbaycan
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => be
            [1] => bel
            [2] => Беларуская мова
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => bg
            [1] => bg_BG
            [2] => български
        )... `

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$languages = array(
    array('af', 'af', 'Afrikaans'),
    array('ar', 'ar', 'العربية', 'rtl'),
    array('az', 'az', 'Azərbaycan'),
    array('be', 'bel', 'Беларуская мова'),
    array('bg', 'bg_BG', 'български'),
    array('bs', 'bs_BA', 'Bosanski'),
    array('ca', 'ca', 'Català'),
    array('cs', 'cs_CZ', 'Čeština'));

$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];

foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
    $locale_key = $value[1];
    $code       = $value[0];
    add_shortcode( $code, function($atts, $content = null, $locale_key) {
        global $lang;
        if ($lang == $locale_key) {
            return $content;
        }
    }); 
}
```

When you use foreach($array as $key => $value) you can access the index via $key and the corresponding value via $value (even if that is an array too).

Comment: foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
    $locale_key = $value][1];
    $code = $value[0];
echo $locale_key; // HERE I GET "bs_BA"
    add_shortcode( $code, function($atts, $content = null, $locale_key) {
        global $lang;
echo $locale_key; // HERE I GET "bs"
        if ($lang == $locale_key) {
            return $content;
        }
    }); 
}

Comment: @Antonio I think there is something wrong in your hook/callback function. But sadly I'm not using Wordpress so I cannot give you a solution. The only thing I can recommend you is to read the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) but I think you already did that.

Comment: here is calback function: 
`function add_shortcode($tag, $func) {
        global $shortcode_tags;
        $shortcode_tags[ $tag ] = $func;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 5],
];

foreach ($array as list($a, $b, $c)) {
    // $a enthält das erste Element des verschachtelten Arrays
    // und $b enthält das zweite Element
    echo "A: $a; B: $b; C: $c\n";
}
?>
```

Try something like above, im sure you will find the solution.

Comment: This code give me same result as my. 
I think that problem is somewhere in function, not in loop.